# Kafka broker restart after one day of downtime - Flaky ISR set

Tags: apache-kafka

In a 5 brokers Kafka cluster ( `2.3.0` ).
At time `t` one broker we will call `brokerA` went down ( hardware issue) and stayed down.
At time `t + 24 hours` we restarted this `brokerA`.

As soon as we restarted it, few minutes later we realised lot of ISR set shrinking, and thus lot of producers were not able to produce ( cause `min_isr` was not met for many partitions).

This had a huge impact on our clients, made also crashed mirror makers instances ( because not able to produce due to min isr).

Our thoughts is that when we restarted `brokerA` it had to catch up with lot of replicas and might have a big impact on network bandwidth, thus making all replicas in the cluster not really able to sync up with other leader , thus shrinking lot of ISR sets.

My question : Is there a way to restart a broker preventing it from fetching from all topic/partition in the same time, like doing them step by step , in order to shape the traffic a little ( going slow..O), and maybe not saturate the network ( maybe CPU) ?